# How to map an object as per key and value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to group an array of objects by an object key then create a new array of objects based on the grouping. I am showing my object below.

```
var oldArr=[
            {
          "_id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f866",
          "allocated_to":"FIELD",
          "zone":"NORTH",
          "state":"DELHI",
          "location":"NEW DELHI",
          "customer_name":"REET INFOTECH",
          "bank_name_of_customer":"YES BANK",
          "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
          "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
          "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
          "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
          "installment_date":"",
          "collection_manager":"",
        },
        {
          "_id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f867",
          "allocated_to":"FIELD",
          "zone":"NORTH",
          "state":"DELHI",
          "location":"Sree Nagar",
          "customer_name":"REET",
          "bank_name_of_customer":"Corporate BANK",
          "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
          "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
          "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
          "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
          "installment_date":"",
          "collection_manager":"",
        },
        {
          "_id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f868",
          "allocated_to":"FIELD",
          "zone":"EAST",
          "state":"Odisha",
          "location":"Bhubaneswar",
          "customer_name":"REET",
          "bank_name_of_customer":"PNB BANK",
          "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
          "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
          "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
          "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
          "installment_date":"",
          "collection_manager":"",
        },
        {
          "_id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f890",
          "allocated_to":"FIELD",
          "zone":"EAST",
          "state":"Assam",
          "location":"Gawhati",
          "customer_name":"REET",
          "bank_name_of_customer":"SBI BANK",
          "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
          "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
          "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
          "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
          "installment_date":"",
          "collection_manager":"",
        }
]
```

I need to make new array which should be group by `zone,state,location` and format is given below.

```
 newdata={
          zone_list: [{
            zone: NORTH,
            state_list: [{    
              state: DELHI,
              location_list: [{
                location: NEW DELHI,
                task_list: [{
                  user_pkId: 5c407834953d7f420d56f866,
                  front_end_manager_name: SONAL,
                  collection_manager: "",
                  area_collection_manager: ASHIS JENA,
                  loan_accounts_assigned: [{
                    allocated_to: FIELD,
                    lk_loan_account_id: LK0000015094,
                    cl_contract_id: LAI-00016881,
                    customer_name: REET INFOTECH,
                    customer_bank_name: YES BANK,
                  }]
                }]
              }]
            },{
              state: JK,
              location_list: [{
                location: Sree Nagar,
                task_list: [{
                  user_pkId: 5c407834953d7f420d56f867,
                  front_end_manager_name: SONAL,
                  collection_manager: "",
                  area_collection_manager: ASHIS JENA,
                  loan_accounts_assigned: [{
                    allocated_to: FIELD,
                    lk_loan_account_id: LK0000015094,
                    cl_contract_id: LAI-00016881,
                    customer_name: REET INFOTECH,
                    customer_bank_name: Corporate BANK,
                  }]
                }]
              }]
            }]
          },{
            zone: EAST,
            state_list: [{    
              state: Odisha,
              location_list: [{
                location: Bhubaneswar,
                task_list: [{
                  user_pkId: 5c407834953d7f420d56f868,
                  front_end_manager_name: SONAL,
                  collection_manager: "",
                  area_collection_manager: ASHIS JENA,
                  loan_accounts_assigned: [{
                    allocated_to: FIELD,
                    lk_loan_account_id: LK0000015094,
                    cl_contract_id: LAI-00016881,
                    customer_name: REET INFOTECH,
                    customer_bank_name: SBI BANK,
                  }]
                }]
              }]
            }]
          }]
        }
```

I am providing my code below.

```
var zonelist=[];
var statelist=[];
 var locationlist=[];
var tasklist=[];
var loanarr=[];
var finalArr=[];
for(var i=0;i<dataArr.length;i++){
          if (zonelist.length > 0) {
            var hasZone=false;
            var zoneindex='';
            for(var j=0;j<zonelist.length;j++){
              if (dataArr[i]['zone']==zonelist[j]['zone']) {
                hasZone=true;
                zoneindex=j;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (hasZone==true) {
              var hasState=false;
              var stateindex='';
              for(var k=0;k<zonelist[zoneindex]['state_list'].length;k++){
                if (dataArr[i]['state']==zonelist[zoneindex]['state_list'][k]['state']) {
                  hasState=true;
                  stateindex=k;
                }
              }
              if (hasState==true) {
                var haslocation=false;
                var locindex='';
                for(var l=0;l<zonelist[zoneindex]['state_list'][stateindex]['location_list'].length;l++){
                  if (dataArr[i]['location']==zonelist[zoneindex]['state_list'][stateindex]['location_list'][l]['location']) {
                    haslocation=true;
                    locindex=l;
                  }
                }
                if (haslocation==true) {
                  var hasUser=false;
                  var userindex='';

                }else{
                  var dataloan={'allocated_to':dataArr[i]['allocated_to'],'lk_loan_account_id':dataArr[i]['lk_loan_account_id'],'cl_contract_id':dataArr[i]['cl_contract_id'],'customer_name':dataArr[i]['customer_name'],'customer_bank_name':dataArr[i]['bank_name_of_customer']};
                  loanarr.push(datatask);
                  var datatask={'user_pkId':dataArr[i]['_id'],'front_end_manager_name':dataArr[i]['front_end_manager_name'],'collection_manager':dataArr[i]['collection_manager'],'area_collection_manager':dataArr[i]['area_collection_manager'],'loan_accounts_assigned':loanarr};
                  tasklist.push(datatask);
                  var dataloc={'location':dataArr[i]['location'],'task_list':tasklist};
                  locationlist.push(dataloc);
                }
              }else{
                var dataloan={'allocated_to':dataArr[i]['allocated_to'],'lk_loan_account_id':dataArr[i]['lk_loan_account_id'],'cl_contract_id':dataArr[i]['cl_contract_id'],'customer_name':dataArr[i]['customer_name'],'customer_bank_name':dataArr[i]['bank_name_of_customer']};
                loanarr.push(datatask);
                var datatask={'user_pkId':dataArr[i]['_id'],'front_end_manager_name':dataArr[i]['front_end_manager_name'],'collection_manager':dataArr[i]['collection_manager'],'area_collection_manager':dataArr[i]['area_collection_manager'],'loan_accounts_assigned':loanarr};
                tasklist.push(datatask);
                var dataloc={'location':dataArr[i]['location'],'task_list':tasklist};
                locationlist.push(dataloc);
                var datastate={'state':dataArr[i]['state'],'location_list':locationlist};
                statelist.push(datastate);
              }
            }else{
              var dataloan={'allocated_to':dataArr[i]['allocated_to'],'lk_loan_account_id':dataArr[i]['lk_loan_account_id'],'cl_contract_id':dataArr[i]['cl_contract_id'],'customer_name':dataArr[i]['customer_name'],'customer_bank_name':dataArr[i]['bank_name_of_customer']};
                loanarr.push(datatask);
              var datatask={'user_pkId':dataArr[i]['_id'],'front_end_manager_name':dataArr[i]['front_end_manager_name'],'collection_manager':dataArr[i]['collection_manager'],'area_collection_manager':dataArr[i]['area_collection_manager'],'loan_accounts_assigned':loanarr};
                tasklist.push(datatask);
              var dataloc={'location':dataArr[i]['location'],'task_list':tasklist};
              locationlist.push(dataloc);
              var datastate={'state':dataArr[i]['state'],'location_list':locationlist};
              statelist.push(datastate);
              var datazone={'zone':dataArr[i]['zone'],'state_list':statelist};
              zonelist.push(datazone);
            }
          }else{
            var dataloan={'allocated_to':dataArr[i]['allocated_to'],'lk_loan_account_id':dataArr[i]['lk_loan_account_id'],'cl_contract_id':dataArr[i]['cl_contract_id'],'customer_name':dataArr[i]['customer_name'],'customer_bank_name':dataArr[i]['bank_name_of_customer']};
            loanarr.push(dataloan);
            var datatask={'user_pkId':dataArr[i]['_id'],'front_end_manager_name':dataArr[i]['front_end_manager_name'],'collection_manager':dataArr[i]['collection_manager'],'area_collection_manager':dataArr[i]['area_collection_manager'],'loan_accounts_assigned':loanarr};
            tasklist.push(datatask);
            var dataloc={'location':dataArr[i]['location'],'task_list':tasklist};
            locationlist.push(dataloc);
            var datastate={'state':dataArr[i]['state'],'location_list':locationlist};
            statelist.push(datastate);
            var datazone={'zone':dataArr[i]['zone'],'state_list':statelist};
            zonelist.push(datazone);
          }
        }
        var findata={'zone_list':zonelist};
        console.log('finaldata',findata);
```

But above code did not give the expected output.

Comment: Could you show us what you've already tried? :-) You should know seeing your reputation that you don't *ask* for code on SO, but rather post your own and people will help you debug.

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question. We will help you fix bugs, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question. P.S. People ask this kind of question a lot...I'm sure you could get some ideas by searching through old questions, as well as reading the PHP docs etc.

Comment: the wanted result does not match the given data. please add the wanted result, according to data or vice versa. plaese add the code, you tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz : I have given my tried code.

Comment: @NinaScholz : Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array for the wanted groups and related keys and take an iterative and recursive approach.

```js
var data = [{ _id: "5c407834953d7f420d56f866", allocated_to: "FIELD", zone: "NORTH", state: "DELHI", location: "NEW DELHI", customer_name: "REET INFOTECH", bank_name_of_customer: "YES BANK", cl_contract_id: "LAI-00016881", lk_loan_account_id: "LK0000015094", front_end_manager_name: "SONAL", area_collection_manager: "ASHIS JENA", installment_date: "", collection_manager: "" }, { _id: "5c407834953d7f420d56f867", allocated_to: "FIELD", zone: "NORTH", state: "DELHI", location: "Sree Nagar", customer_name: "REET", bank_name_of_customer: "Corporate BANK", cl_contract_id: "LAI-00016881", lk_loan_account_id: "LK0000015094", front_end_manager_name: "SONAL", area_collection_manager: "ASHIS JENA", installment_date: "", collection_manager: "" }, { _id: "5c407834953d7f420d56f868", allocated_to: "FIELD", zone: "EAST", state: "Odisha", location: "Bhubaneswar", customer_name: "REET", bank_name_of_customer: "PNB BANK", cl_contract_id: "LAI-00016881", lk_loan_account_id: "LK0000015094", front_end_manager_name: "SONAL", area_collection_manager: "ASHIS JENA", installment_date: "", collection_manager: "" }, { _id: "5c407834953d7f420d56f890", allocated_to: "FIELD", zone: "EAST", state: "Assam", location: "Gawhati", customer_name: "REET", bank_name_of_customer: "SBI BANK", cl_contract_id: "LAI-00016881", lk_loan_account_id: "LK0000015094", front_end_manager_name: "SONAL", area_collection_manager: "ASHIS JENA", installment_date: "", collection_manager: "" }],
    groups = [
        ['zone_list', 'zone'],
        ['state_list', 'state'],
        ['location_list', 'location'],
        ['task_list', '_id', 'front_end_manager_name', 'area_collection_manager', 'collection_manager'],
        ['loan_accounts_assigned', 'lk_loan_account_id', 'allocated_to', 'cl_contract_id', 'customer_name', 'bank_name_of_customer']
    ],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        groups.reduce((t, [group, ...keys]) => {
            var temp = (t[group] = t[group] || []).find(p => o[keys[0]] === p[keys[0]]);
            if (!temp) {
                temp = Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })));
                t[group].push(temp);
            }
            return temp;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, {});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `loan_accounts_assigned` should be an array object.

Comment: you get the idea.

Comment: yes, I did like `groups = [['zone_list', 'zone'], ['state_list', 'state'], ['location_list', 'location'],['task_list','task_list']],
    finalGroup = 'loan_accounts_assigned',` but all data are appending into `loan_accounts_assigned` where some of them will stay within `task_list`. Can you check my output format and guide me.

Comment: you take a reformatting without some exposed rules.

Comment: Again I changed `groups = [['zone_list', 'zone'], ['state_list', 'state'], ['location_list', 'location'],['task_list','_id','front_end_manager_name','area_collection_manager','collection_manager']],` but only `_id` is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Following code does not give you full correct result, but you should get a better sense of how to do it.
Reference for .reduce() is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
var oldArr=[
    {
      "id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f866",
      "allocated_to":"FIELD",
      "zone":"NORTH",
      "state":"DELHI",
      "location":"NEW DELHI",
      "customer_name":"REET INFOTECH"
    },
    {
      "id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f867",
      "allocated_to":"FIELD",
      "zone":"NORTH",
      "state":"JK",
      "location":"Sree Nagar",
      "customer_name":"REET"
    },
    {
      "id":"5c407834953d7f420d56f868",
      "allocated_to":"FIELD",
      "zone":"EAST",
      "state":"Odisha",
      "location":"Bhubaneswar",
      "customer_name":"REET"
    }
]

let result = oldArr.reduce(
    function(acc, curr){
        var sameZone =  acc.find(function (accData){ return accData.zone===curr.zone})
        if(sameZone){
            sameZone.state_list.push({
                state: curr.state,
                    task_list: [{
                        user_pkId: curr.id,
                        loan_accounts_assigned: [{
                            customer_name: curr.customer_name
                        }]
                    }]
            })
        }else{
            acc.push({
                zone: curr.zone,
                state_list: [{
                    state: curr.state,
                    task_list: [{
                        user_pkId: curr.id,
                        loan_accounts_assigned: [{
                            customer_name: curr.customer_name
                        }]
                    }]
                }]           
            })          
        }        
        return acc;
    }, []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Here state is not mapped properly. If I am changing the state name from `JK` to `DELHI` then it could not map.