# Could not group the array as per the key value using Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to group my array values as per some key value using Jquery/Javascript but as per my code I could not get it. I am explaining my code below.

```
var dataArr=[
            {
              "login_id":"9937229853",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"NORTH",
              "state":"DELHI",
              "location":"NEW DELHI",
              "customer_name":"REET INFOTECH",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"YES BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "1stcoll",
              "reso_status": "1stres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229853",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"NORTH",
              "state":"DELHI",
              "location":"NEW DELHI",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"Corporate BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "2ndcoll",
              "reso_status": "2ndres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229867",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"EAST",
              "state":"Odisha",
              "location":"Bhubaneswar",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"PNB BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "3rdcoll",
              "reso_status": "3rdres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229867",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"EAST",
              "state":"Assam",
              "location":"Gawhati",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"SBI BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "4thcoll",
              "reso_status": "4thres"
            }
        ]
```

Here I need to group the all json array as per `zone,state,location and login_id`. My working code is given below.

```
 groups = [
          ['zone_list', 'zone'],
          ['state_list', 'state'],
          ['location_list', 'location'],
          ['task_list', 'login_id', 'front_end_manager_name', 'area_collection_manager', 'collection_manager'],
          ['loan_accounts_assigned', 'lk_loan_account_id', 'allocated_to', 'cl_contract_id', 'customer_name', 'customer_bank_name'],
          ['feedback_detail', 'coll_cat', 'reso_status']
      ],
      finalGroup = 'task_list',
      result = dataArr.reduce((r, o) => {
          groups.reduce((t, [group, ...keys]) => {
              var temp = (t[group] = t[group] || []).find(p => o[keys[0]] === p[keys[0]]);
              if (!temp) {
                  temp = Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })));
                  t[group].push(temp);
              }
              return temp;
          }, r);
          return r;
      }, {});
      console.log(result);
```

But my issue is I can group the whole value as per zone,state and location but as per `login_id` the grouping can not be made. I need to group as per `zone,state,location and login_id`. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Working snippet**:

```js
var dataArr=[{"login_id":"9937229853","allocated_to":"FIELD","zone":"NORTH","state":"DELHI","location":"NEW DELHI","customer_name":"REET INFOTECH","bank_name_of_customer":"YES BANK","cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881","lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094","front_end_manager_name":"SONAL","area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA","installment_date":"","collection_manager":"","coll_cat":"1stcoll","reso_status":"1stres"},{"login_id":"9937229853","allocated_to":"FIELD","zone":"NORTH","state":"DELHI","location":"NEW DELHI","customer_name":"REET","bank_name_of_customer":"Corporate BANK","cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881","lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094","front_end_manager_name":"SONAL","area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA","installment_date":"","collection_manager":"","coll_cat":"2ndcoll","reso_status":"2ndres"},{"login_id":"9937229867","allocated_to":"FIELD","zone":"EAST","state":"Odisha","location":"Bhubaneswar","customer_name":"REET","bank_name_of_customer":"PNB BANK","cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881","lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094","front_end_manager_name":"SONAL","area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA","installment_date":"","collection_manager":"","coll_cat":"3rdcoll","reso_status":"3rdres"},{"login_id":"9937229867","allocated_to":"FIELD","zone":"EAST","state":"Assam","location":"Gawhati","customer_name":"REET","bank_name_of_customer":"SBI BANK","cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881","lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094","front_end_manager_name":"SONAL","area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA","installment_date":"","collection_manager":"","coll_cat":"4thcoll","reso_status":"4thres"}],
    groups=[['zone_list','zone'],['state_list','state'],['location_list','location'],['task_list','login_id','front_end_manager_name','area_collection_manager','collection_manager'],['loan_accounts_assigned','lk_loan_account_id','allocated_to','cl_contract_id','customer_name','customer_bank_name'],['feedback_detail','coll_cat','reso_status']],
  finalGroup = 'task_list',
  result = dataArr.reduce((r, o) => {
    groups.reduce((t, [group, ...keys]) => {
      var temp = (t[group] = t[group] || []).find(p => o[keys[0]] === p[keys[0]]);
      if (!temp) {
        temp = Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })));
        t[group].push(temp);
      }
      return temp;
    }, r);
    return r;
  }, {});
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you include the current and expected output at the question?

Comment: Please write a rules for sorting asc/desc for each field? and order of field that should be sorted the same as you say ?

Comment: yes sure I am giving also the expected output.

Comment: This is the exact code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54251605/3082296), but from an alt account?

Comment: yes but its also not working as expected.

Comment: I agree, seeing an example of how you want the output structured would help. I'm not clear on how you want things grouped.

Comment: please add what does not work.

Comment: @showdev : If you can check the output of console message it is expected output but in case of same `login_id` there should be 2 set of `loan_accounts_assigned` value but now on ly one is coming.

Comment: You cant group by id (login id), do you mean sort?

Answer (score 1):

I see in your data that you have indeed the same `login_id` occurring twice in the input, and that the difference between those records is (amongst others) in the `customer_name` field.

You have this field `customer_name` listed in the `groups` structure, but the code does not use it to distinguish records. I suppose the code was not originally intended for that and assumed that such a field would be functionally dependent on the first key in the list (i.e. it assumed that the same `lk_loan_account_id` would imply the same `customer_name`), but this is evidently not the case in your data.

From a business point of view, it seems quite logical that a loan account id would uniquely identify the customer name, so maybe you should also check the validity of your input data.

If however, the input data is as expected, and it should differentiate on all fields listed in the `groups` structure, then replace the following line of code:

```
var temp = (t[group] = t[group] || []).find(p => o[keys[0]] === p[keys[0]]);
```

with:

```
var temp = (t[group] = t[group] || []).find(p => keys.every(key => o[key] === p[key]));
```

With this change the result would still have one grouped item for that duplicate `login_id`, but it would have two nested entries for the `loan_accounts_assigned` array property instead of just one.

Side note: you have a wrong field name in the `groups` structure: `customer_bank_name` should be `bank_name_of_customer`.

```js
var dataArr=[
  {
    "login_id":"9937229853",
    "allocated_to":"FIELD",
    "zone":"NORTH",
    "state":"DELHI",
    "location":"NEW DELHI",
    "customer_name":"REET INFOTECH",
    "bank_name_of_customer":"YES BANK",
    "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
    "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
    "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
    "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
    "installment_date":"",
    "collection_manager":"",
    "coll_cat": "1stcoll",
    "reso_status": "1stres"
  },
  {
    "login_id":"9937229853",
    "allocated_to":"FIELD",
    "zone":"NORTH",
    "state":"DELHI",
    "location":"NEW DELHI",
    "customer_name":"REET",
    "bank_name_of_customer":"Corporate BANK",
    "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
    "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
    "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
    "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
    "installment_date":"",
    "collection_manager":"",
    "coll_cat": "2ndcoll",
    "reso_status": "2ndres"
  },
  {
    "login_id":"9937229867",
    "allocated_to":"FIELD",
    "zone":"EAST",
    "state":"Odisha",
    "location":"Bhubaneswar",
    "customer_name":"REET",
    "bank_name_of_customer":"PNB BANK",
    "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
    "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
    "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
    "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
    "installment_date":"",
    "collection_manager":"",
    "coll_cat": "3rdcoll",
    "reso_status": "3rdres"
  },
  {
    "login_id":"9937229867",
    "allocated_to":"FIELD",
    "zone":"EAST",
    "state":"Assam",
    "location":"Gawhati",
    "customer_name":"REET",
    "bank_name_of_customer":"SBI BANK",
    "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
    "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
    "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
    "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
    "installment_date":"",
    "collection_manager":"",
    "coll_cat": "4thcoll",
    "reso_status": "4thres"
  }
]

var groups = [
        ['zone_list', 'zone'],
        ['state_list', 'state'],
        ['location_list', 'location'],
        ['task_list', 'login_id', 'front_end_manager_name', 'area_collection_manager', 'collection_manager'],
        ['loan_accounts_assigned', 'lk_loan_account_id', 'allocated_to', 'cl_contract_id', 'customer_name', 'bank_name_of_customer'],
        ['feedback_detail', 'coll_cat', 'reso_status']
    ],
    finalGroup = 'task_list',
    result = dataArr.reduce((r, o) => {
        groups.reduce((t, [group, ...keys]) => {
            var temp = (t[group] = t[group] || []).find(p => keys.every(key => o[key] === p[key]));
            if (!temp) {
                temp = Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })));
                t[group].push(temp);
            }
            return temp;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think you've deduced the OP's desired output. Just for kicks, do you mind including a working example to see the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to group based on specific key from Array of JSON with Easy way then I suggest using Javascript utility library **underscore js or [Lo-dash js](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)**. See below example that might solve your problem with readable code.

```
_.groupBy(dataArr,"login_id");
_.groupBy(dataArr,"state");
_.groupBy(dataArr,"zone");
```

```js
var dataArr=[
            {
              "login_id":"9937229853",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"NORTH",
              "state":"DELHI",
              "location":"NEW DELHI",
              "customer_name":"REET INFOTECH",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"YES BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "1stcoll",
              "reso_status": "1stres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229853",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"NORTH",
              "state":"DELHI",
              "location":"NEW DELHI",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"Corporate BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "2ndcoll",
              "reso_status": "2ndres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229867",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"EAST",
              "state":"Odisha",
              "location":"Bhubaneswar",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"PNB BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "3rdcoll",
              "reso_status": "3rdres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229867",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"EAST",
              "state":"Assam",
              "location":"Gawhati",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"SBI BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "4thcoll",
              "reso_status": "4thres"
            }
        ];
        
       
       //usage _.groupBy(jsonArrayOfObjects,"key");
       var groupByLoginId=_.groupBy(dataArr,"login_id");
        console.log(groupByLoginId);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple groupBy function for this:

```js
var dataArr=[
            {
              "login_id":"9937229853",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"NORTH",
              "state":"DELHI",
              "location":"NEW DELHI",
              "customer_name":"REET INFOTECH",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"YES BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "1stcoll",
              "reso_status": "1stres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229853",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"NORTH",
              "state":"DELHI",
              "location":"NEW DELHI",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"Corporate BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "2ndcoll",
              "reso_status": "2ndres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229867",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"EAST",
              "state":"Odisha",
              "location":"Bhubaneswar",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"PNB BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "3rdcoll",
              "reso_status": "3rdres"
            },
            {
              "login_id":"9937229867",
              "allocated_to":"FIELD",
              "zone":"EAST",
              "state":"Assam",
              "location":"Gawhati",
              "customer_name":"REET",
              "bank_name_of_customer":"SBI BANK",
              "cl_contract_id":"LAI-00016881",
              "lk_loan_account_id":"LK0000015094",
              "front_end_manager_name":"SONAL",
              "area_collection_manager":"ASHIS JENA",
              "installment_date":"",
              "collection_manager":"",
              "coll_cat": "4thcoll",
              "reso_status": "4thres"
            }
        ];

function groupBy(fields,data){
  var groups={};
  data.forEach(function(dataItem){
     var key=fields.reduce(function(result,fieldName){
        return (result && result+'&' || '')+fieldName+':'+(dataItem[fieldName])||'NULL';
     },'');
     if(!(key in groups))
         groups[key]=[];
     groups[key].push(dataItem);
    
  });
  return groups;
}

console.log(groupBy(['zone','state'],dataArr));
```